# Como converter NSData para URL

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, apple

Amigos tenho uma imagem gravada no SQLite, 
li a imagem e coloquei em uma variável NSData

Agora preciso dar o play nesse NSData mas o o componente espera uma URL

```
 NSURL *urlVideoFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringVideoPath];
//NSAssert(urlVideoFile, @"Expected not nil video url");

_playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
_playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:**urlVideoFile**];

_playerViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
_playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;

[self.view addSubview:_playerViewController.view];
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
```

Obrigado,

Comment: Você está tentando mostrar uma imagem num player de vídeo?

Comment: Basta voce salvar a NSData no disco usando o metodo NSFileManager writeToURL e usa essa url

Answer (score 1):

**[ R E S O L V I D O ]**

```
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"teste.mp4"]];
[data writeToFile:databasePath atomically:YES];


 NSURL *urlVideoFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:databasePath];

_playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
_playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:urlVideoFile];

_playerViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
_playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;

[self.view addSubview:_playerViewController.view];
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
```